# Unable to port forward from server to local service

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I'm trying to access a webpage served on my machine from a VPS, but when using the `curl` tool, I get a error (Empty reply from server).

I'm running a basic server on port 8000 with python `python -m http.server`

Locally I can get a html response with `curl localhost:8000`

Now when I try a ssh connection with `ssh -R 8000:localhost:8000 myhost`. And then try the same curl command I get the following output "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

I've tried to forward the traffic to Google and it worked, so it may be some other problem.

I'm on Windows BTW.